# Chef powershell_out SystemCallError The filename or extension is too long. - CreateProcessAsUserW failed

Tags: ruby, windows, powershell, chef-infra

I created a custom resource `gmsa` to create Windows Active Directory Group Managed Service Accounts. I am getting an interesting error message when calling this custom resource, which I am currently getting with great consistency in my Jenkins pipeline kitchen test but not in my local kitchen testing:

```
================================================================================
Error executing action `create` on resource 'gmsa[gMSA.sql]'
================================================================================

SystemCallError
---------------
The filename or extension is too long. - CreateProcessAsUserW failed.

Cookbook Trace:
---------------
C:/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/adr_env_common/resources/gmsa.rb:123:in `ps_ad_object'
C:/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/adr_env_common/resources/gmsa.rb:154:in `alternate_id_from_dn'
C:/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/adr_env_common/resources/gmsa.rb:241:in `block in class_from_file'
```

The reference to line 123 in the `gmsa.rb` file is a call to `powershell_out`

I am curious if `powershell_out` is attempting to create a temporary file and it is hitting a file path character limitation (I believe this is 260 characters for Windows)

Has anyone else experienced anything like this with the `powershell_out` method? If so, any thoughts on a workaround or solution?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

---

EDIT (7/8/2020):

I tried adding the following registry setting before calling the custom resource to see if it would allow for bypassing the 260 character filename limit but no luck:

```
registry_key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem' do
  values [{
    name: 'LongPathsEnabled',
    type: :dword,
    data: 1
  }]
  action :create
  notifies :reboot_now, 'reboot[Reboot For Registry Setting]', :immediately
end

reboot 'Reboot For Registry Setting' do
  action :nothing
  reason 'Cannot continue Chef run without a reboot.'
  delay_mins 1
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It turned out in my case that this error was a complete misdirection. We had an AD security group in our testing domain that essentially "filled up" after repeated pipeline runs and no cleanup. After purging the members from that group and running the pipeline again everything worked just fine.